# How to increment a node in an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, powershell

I have an xml file that looks something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PreviousFolderVersion>2.0.0.0</PreviousFolderVersion>
  <FileMajor>2</FileMajor>
  <FileMinor>0</FileMinor>
  <FileBuild>0</FileBuild>
  <FileRevision>0</FileRevision>
  <ProductMajor>2</ProductMajor>
  <ProductMinor>0</ProductMinor>
  <ProductBuild>0</ProductBuild>
  <ProductRevision>0</ProductRevision>
  <FolderMajor>2</FolderMajor>
  <FolderMinor>0</FolderMinor>
  <FolderBuild>0</FolderBuild>
  <FolderRevision>0</FolderRevision>
  <FileVersion>2.0.0.0</FileVersion>
  <ProductVersion>2.0.0.0</ProductVersion>
  <FolderVersion>2.0.0.0</FolderVersion>
</Settings>
```

What would be the best way to increment and update the version nodes?

I've been trying variations of what is described on this page but :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sonam_rastogi_blogs/archive/2014/05/14/update-xml-file-using-powershell.aspx

such as this:

```
$path = "C:\Workspaces\Ahltaprint\Build\Settings.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path) 
$fileBuild = $xml.Settings.FileBuild
$newChild = $xml.CreateElement("FileBuild")
$newChild.InnerText = "100"
$xml.Settings.ReplaceChild($newChild, $fileBuild)
$xml.Save($path)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm getting an error as follows:

> Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "0", for "ReplaceChild" to
>   type "System.Xml.XmlNode": "Cannot convert the "0" value of type
>   "System.String" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode"."At 
>   C:\Workspaces\Ahltaprint\Build\buildawp.ps1:157 char:1
>   + $xml.Settings.ReplaceChild($newChild, $fileBuild)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there are multiple ways to work with XML files in Powershell, but I usually find working with XPath expressions the easiest:

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode("/Settings/FileBuild").InnerText = "2"
$xml.Settings.FileBuild         # Produces "2"
```

By the way, the reason that your code fragment didn't work is because although `$xml.Settings` is of type `XmlElement`, `$xml.Settings.FileBuild` is **not** - rather, it is a string, probably because it is a "simple" element, i.e. without child elements or attributes.

If you get the FileBuild like this, it *is* of type `XmlElement`, and the rest of your replacement code will work:

```
$fileBuild = $xml.Settings.GetElementsByTagName("FileBuild")[0]
```

You can verify this by calling `GetType()` on a variable or expression:

```
$fileBuild.GetType()   # Produces XmlElement
```

Comment: Astrotrain,  thank you for your suggestions and examples!